# Extract substring in R from string with fixed start position and end point as a character found

Tags: regex, r

I want to do the following extraction in R.

I have a column which has links like these
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2569314/companycredits

I want to extract the tt2569314 out of this and store it in a new column.

The way I want to do it is, say, take substring of column where start position is LEN(http://www.imdb.com/) and end position is dynamic based on when the first '/' is found after the start position.

I want this to be kind of a mixture of SUBSTR and INSTR in SQL.

Please advise.

Comment: Why do you want to do it this way?

Comment: I mean.. I do it that way in SQL. You can suggest any other way.

I think this way is a bit more efficient than searching for the / using regex. By giving a fixed start position, I am directly telling the code to go that index without wasting any time.
For the end position, I don't have any option as the numerical after tt could be of variable length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
a<-"http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2569314/companycredits"
sub("http://www.imdb.com/.+/(.+)/.+","\\1" ,a)
#[1] "tt2569314"
```

Comment: http://www.imdb.com/title/something/tt2569314/companycredits would fail in this case.....it.is not failsafe

Answer (score 2):

If all the links are similar in path structure, you can use the `dirname`

```
x <- "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2569314/companycredits"
sub("(.*)[/]", "", dirname(x))
# [1] "tt2569314"
```

Or you can paste together a regular expression with the base URL

```
y <- "http://www.imdb.com"
sub(paste0(y, "[/](.*)[/](.*)[/](.*)"), "\\2", x)
# [1] "tt2569314"
```

Or you may even be able to get away with this:

```
basename(dirname(x))
# [1] "tt2569314"
```

It's a bit more drawn out if you use the substring.  But `stringr` has a couple of helpful functions.

```
library(stringr)
s1 <- str_locate_all(x, "[/]")[[1]]
s2 <- str_locate(x, "http://www.imdb.com/title")
m <- match(s2[,2]+1, s1[,1])
substr(x, s1[m,1]+1, s1[m+1,1]-1)
# [1] "tt2569314"
```

Comment: `substr(x, nchar("http://www.imdb.com/title/") + 1, nchar(dirname(x)) )` for a no regex solution.

Comment: @AvinashRaj - well, their description is wrong then. They say they want to end at the first `/` after the `http://www.imdb.com/`, but this would just give `"title"`

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
 str1 <- "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2569314/companycredits"
 library(httr)
 gsub("^[^/]*\\/|\\/[^/]*", "", parse_url(str1)$path)
 #[1] "tt2569314"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this also,

```
> x <- "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2569314/companycredits"
> m <- regexpr("^http://www.imdb.com/[^/]*/\\K[^/]+", x, perl=TRUE)
> regmatches(x, m)
[1] "tt2569314"
```